# Lisp Extraction Mission

Tags: code-golf, array, lisp

In Lisp style languages, a list is usually defined like this:

```
(list 1 2 3)
```

For the purposes of this challenge, all lists will only contain positive integers or other lists. We will also leave out the `list` keyword at the start, so the list will now look like this:

```
(1 2 3)
```

We can get the first element of a list by using `car`. For example:

```
(car (1 2 3))
==> 1
```

And we can get the original list with the first element removed with `cdr`:

```
(cdr (1 2 3))
==> (2 3)
```

Important: `cdr` will always return a list, even if that list would have a single element:

```
(cdr (1 2))
==> (2)
(car (cdr (1 2)))
==> 2
```

Lists can also be inside other lists:

```
(cdr (1 2 3 (4 5 6)))
==> (2 3 (4 5 6))
```

Write a program that returns code that uses `car` and `cdr` to return a certain integer in a list. In the code that your program returns, you can assume that the list is stored in `l`, the target integer is in `l` somewhere, and that all the integers are unique.

Examples:

Input: `(6 1 3) 3`

Output: `(car (cdr (cdr l)))`

Input: `(4 5 (1 2 (7) 9 (10 8 14))) 8`

Output: `(car (cdr (car (cdr (cdr (cdr (cdr (car (cdr (cdr l))))))))))`

Input: `(1 12 1992) 1`

Output: `(car l)`

Comment: Can we take input with the integer first and the list second?

Comment: @MartinBüttner Sure.

Comment: What about `(1 2 3) 16`, shall we return `()`?

Comment: @coredump Good question. You can assume that the target integer will always be in the expression, so a case like `(1 2 3) 16` will never show up.

Comment: Can we receive two inputs, one for the list and one for the integer?

Comment: Is the list always a list (and not just a number)? Can any of the sublists be empty? Can I use square brackets for the input?

Comment: May we assume that the list is properly formatted just like in the question (so always one space between elements, no spaces between `)`, etc.

Comment: Similarly, can we assume a different whitespace format? E.g. spaces around parentheses, or one space after each list element (e.g. `(1 (2 3 ) )`)?

Comment: @Blackhole No, it goes in on one input.

Comment: @orlp Yes, you can assume the lisp will always be properly formatted.

Comment: @MartinBüttner No, the only format that will be present is the one used in the examples -- that is, one space between each element, and no spaces between parentheses.

Comment: @aditsu The list is always a list. The sublists won't be empty. You cannot use square brackets for the input.

Comment: This invalidates a lot of answers, then. I don't think you can maintain that this way.

Comment: @Blackhole Ah, does it? I'm not familiar with most of the languages used in the answers. I'll retract my previous statement then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## CJam, 59

```
q"()""[]"er~{:AL>{0jA1<e_-_A(?j'l/"(car l)"@{2'dt}&*}"l"?}j
```

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q%22()%22%22%5B%5D%22er~%7B%3AAL%3E%7B0jA1%3Ce_-_A(%3Fj'l%2F%22(car%20l)%22%40%7B2'dt%7D%26*%7D%22l%22%3F%7Dj&input=(4%205%20(1%202%20(7)%209%20(10%208%2014)))%208)

**Explanation:**

```
q                 read the input
"()""[]"er        replace parentheses with square brackets
~                 evaluate the string, pushing an array and a number
{…}j              calculate with memoized recursion using the array as the argument
                   and the number as the memozied value for argument 0
  :A              store the argument in A
  L>              practically, check if A is an array
                   if A is a (non-empty) array, compare with an empty array
                   (result 1, true)
                   if A is a number, slice the empty array from that position
                   (result [], false)
    {…}           if A is an array
      0j          get the memoized value for 0 (the number to search)
      A1<         slice A keeping only its first element
      e_          flatten array
      -           set difference - true iff the number was not in the array
      _           duplicate the result (this is the car/cdr indicator)
      A(          uncons A from left, resulting in the "cdr" followed by the "car"
      ?           choose the cdr if the number was not in the flattened first item,
                   else choose the car
      j           call the block recursively with the chosen value as the argument
      'l/         split the result around the 'l' character
      "(car l)"   push this string
      @           bring up the car/cdr indicator
      {…}&        if true (indicating cdr)
        2'dt      set the character in position 2 to 'd'
      *           join the split pieces using the resulting string as a separator
    "l"           else (if A is not an array) just push "l"
                   (we know that when we get to a number, it is the right number)
    ?             end if
```

Answer (score 10):

## Common Lisp, 99

The following 99 bytes solution is a CL version of the nice [Scheme answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/58876/903).

```lisp
(defun g(l n &optional(o'l))(if(eql n l)o(and(consp l)(or(g(car l)n`(car,o))(g(cdr l)n`(cdr,o))))))
```

I originally tried to make use of `position` and `position-if`, but it turned out to be not as compact as I would have liked (209 bytes):

```lisp
(lambda(L x &aux(p'l))(labels((f(S &aux e)(cons(or(position x S)(position-if(lambda(y)(if(consp y)(setf e(f y))))S)(return-from f()))e)))(dolist(o(print(f L))p)(dotimes(i o)(setf p`(cdr,p)))(setf p`(car,p)))))
```

#### Expanded

```lisp
(lambda
  (l x &aux (p 'l))
  (labels ((f (s &aux e)
             (cons
              (or (position x s)
                  (position-if
                   (lambda (y)
                     (if (consp y)
                         (setf e (f y))))
                   s)
                  (return-from f nil))
              e)))
    (dolist (o (print (f l)) p)
      (dotimes (i o) (setf p `(cdr ,p)))
      (setf p `(car ,p)))))
```

#### Example

```lisp
(funcall *fun* '(4 5 (1 2 (7) 9 (10 8 14))) 14)
```

The list is quoted, but if you really want, I can use a macro. 
The returned value is<sup>[1]</sup>:

```lisp
(CAR (CDR (CDR (CAR (CDR (CDR (CDR (CDR (CAR (CDR (CDR L)))))))))))
```

For tests, I used to generate a lambda form where `l` was a variable:

```lisp
(LAMBDA (#:G854) (CAR (CDR (CDR (CAR (CDR (CDR (CDR (CDR (CAR (CDR (CDR #:G854))))))))))))
```

Calling this with the original list returns 14.

---

[1] `(caddar (cddddr (caddr l)))` would be nice too

Comment: You answered a question about Lisp _with Lisp!_ It's Lisp-ception!

Comment: @DanTheMan Lisp-ception is pretty much what defines Lisp ;-)

Answer (score 9):

## [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina), <s>170</s> <s>142</s> <s>125</s> <s>115</s> <s>114</s> <s>87</s> <s>84</s> <s>83</s> <s>75</s> <s>73</s> <s>70</s> <s>69</s> <s>68</s> 67 bytes

Yay, <s>less than 50% of</s> more than 100 bytes off my first attempt. :)

```
\b(.+)\b.* \1$
(
^.
l
\(
a
+`a *\)|\d


d
+`(.*[l)])(\w)
(c$2r $1)
```

To run the code from a single file, use the `-s` flag.

I'm still not convinced this is optimal... I won't have a lot of time over the next few days, I will add an explanation eventually.

Answer (score 5):

## Pyth, 62 bytes

```
JvXz"() ,][")u?qJQG&=J?K}Quu+GHNY<J1)hJtJ++XWK"(cdr "\d\aG\)\l
```

Try it online: [Demonstration](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?input=%286%201%203%29%0A3&test_suite=0&code=JvXz%22%28%29%20%2C%5D%5B%22%29u%3FqJQG%26%3DJ%3FK%7DQuu%2BGHNY%3CJ1%29hJtJ%2B%2BXWK%22%28cdr%20%22%5Cd%5CaG%5C%29%5Cl&input_size=2&test_suite_input=%286%201%203%29%0A3%0A%284%205%20%281%202%20%287%29%209%20%2810%208%2014%29%29%29%0A8%0A%281%2012%201992%29%0A1) or [Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?input=%286%201%203%29%0A3&test_suite=1&code=JvXz%22%28%29%20%2C%5D%5B%22%29u%3FqJQG%26%3DJ%3FK%7DQuu%2BGHNY%3CJ1%29hJtJ%2B%2BXWK%22%28cdr%20%22%5Cd%5CaG%5C%29%5Cl&input_size=2&test_suite_input=%286%201%203%29%0A3%0A%284%205%20%281%202%20%287%29%209%20%2810%208%2014%29%29%29%0A8%0A%281%2012%201992%29%0A1)

#### Explanation:

The first bit `JvXz"() ,][")` replaces the chars `"() "` with the chars `"[],"` in the input string, which ends up in a representation of a Python-style list. I evaluate it and store it in `J`.

Then I reduce the string `G = "l"` with `u...\l`. I apply the inner function `...` repeatedly to `G`, until the value of `G` doesn't change anymore and then print `G`.

The inner function does the following: If `J` is already equal to the input number, than don't modify `G` (`?qJQG`). Otherwise I'll flatten the the list `J[:1]` and check if the input number is in that list and save this to the variable `K` (`K}Quu+GHNY<J1)`). Notice that Pyth doesn't have a flatten operator, so this is takes quite a few bytes. If `K` is true, than I update J with `J[0]`, otherwise with `J[1:]` (`=J?KhJtJ`). And then I replace `G` with `"(cdr G)"` and replace the `d` the `a`, if `K` is true (`++XWK"(cdr "\d\aG\)`).

Answer (score 5):

### Scheme (R5RS), 102 bytes

```
(let g((l(read))(n(read))(o'l))(if(pair? l)(or(g(car l)n`(car,o))(g(cdr l)n`(cdr,o)))(and(eq? n l)o)))
```

Answer (score 1):

### PHP - 177 bytes

I've added some newlines for readability:

```php
function f($a,$o,$n){foreach($a as$v){if($n===$v||$s=f($v,$o,$n))return
'(car '.($s?:$o).')';$o="(cdr $o)";}}function l($s,$n){echo f(eval(strtr
("return$s;",'() ','[],')),l,$n);}
```

Here is the ungolfed version:

```php
function extractPhp($list, $output, $number)
{
    foreach ($list as $value)
    {
        if (is_int($value))
        {
            if ($value === $number) {
                return '(car '. $output .')';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $subOutput = extractPhp($value, $output, $number);
            if ($subOutput !== null) {
                return '(car '. $subOutput .')';
            }
        }

        $output = '(cdr '. $output .')';
    }
}

function extractLisp($stringList, $number)
{
    $phpCode = 'return '. strtr($stringList, '() ','[],') .';';
    $list = eval($phpCode);
    echo extractPhp($list, 'l', $number);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, <s>190</s> 188 bytes

`l "(4 5 (1 2 (7) 9 (10 8 14)))" 8`

evaluates to

`"(car (cdr (car (cdr (cdr (cdr (cdr (car (cdr (cdr l))))))))))"`

```
l(h:s)n=c$i(show n)s""""
i n(h:s)t l|h>'/'&&h<':'=i n s(t++[h])l|t==n='a':l|h=='('=j$'a':l|h==')'=j$tail$dropWhile(=='d')l|0<1=j$'d':l where j=i n s""
c[]="l"
c(h:s)="(c"++h:"r "++c s++")"
```

Comment: You can turn `(`and `c` in function `c` into a string: `c(h:s)="(c"++h:...`

Comment: Wow, didn't think that would work with `h` being a Char!

Answer (score 0):

## Common Lisp, <s>168</s> 155 bytes

Some stupid recursion thing, it could probably be condensed a bit more:

```
(lambda(l e)(labels((r(l o)(setf a(car l)d(cdr l)x`(car,o)y`(cdr,o))(if(equal e a)x(if(atom a)(r d y)(if(find e l)(r d y)(if d(r d y)(r a x)))))))(r l'l)))
```

Pretty printed:

```
(lambda (l e)
  (labels ((r (l o)
             (setf a (car l) d (cdr l)
                   x `(car ,o) y `(cdr ,o))
             (if (equal e a) x
                 (if (atom a)
                     (r d y)
                     (if (find e l)
                         (r d y)
                         (if d
                             (r d y)
                             (r a x)))))))
    (r l 'l)))
```